# How to read the comment of method and add annotation accordingly?

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection

Suppose I have the following method:

```
/** Account Types */
@ResponseBody
@Secured("ROLE_AccountTypes")
@RequestMapping(value = "/accountTypes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<T> getAccountTypes() {

  return accountSrv.getAccountTypes();
}
```

Now I want to put the comment of the method in a custom annotation programmatically. How is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but not using reflection. Comments do not exist in run-time, only in the source. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: I only want to manipulate the source code with respect to it's comment.

Comment: You will need a java parser that supports comments, use it to parse the source code, build its Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), and modify it accordingly. Quick googling brought me http://javaparser.org/, check it out.

Comment: An alternative that handles comments is our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit with its Java 8 front end, see http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html.   DMS provides APIs to walk the tree, and inspect the comments, change the tree.  Uniquely, it provides means to modify the tree using fragments of (Java) target language surface syntax, which will make inserting  your custom annotation easier.